# Regex to remove EVEN lines

Tags: regex

I need help to build a regex that can remove EVEN lines in a plain textfile.

Given this input:

> line1
>   line2
> line3
> line4
> line5
> line6

It would output this:

> line1
> line3
> line5

Thanks !

Comment: Do you *really* need to use a regex for this? It seems pretty tough if at all possible. It is extremely simple to handle in awk or sed for instance.

Comment: That's not "odd", that is "even".

Comment: We need more information. Is there a programming language involved? Why do you think regex is the right choice here?

Comment: When I was a mechanic, before being a programmer, we used to have a saying "use the right tool for the right job".  Are you sure that regex is the right tool for this?

Lastly, how do you define a line? CR, LF, CR & LF, or are you using ReadLine? the file might only be one line deep but have a few thousand characters.

Comment: @bart: Only if you brain zero indexed, right? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you don't use regex for that. With your favourite language, iterate the file, use a counter and do modulus. eg with awk (*nix)

```
$ awk 'NR%2==1' file
line1
line3
line5
```

even lines:

```
$ awk 'NR%2==0' file
line2
line4
line6
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you do a search-and-replace-all-matches on

```
^(.*)\r?\n.*
```

in "`^` matches start-of-line mode" and "`.` doesn't match linebreaks mode"; replacing with

```
\1
```

then you lose every even line.

E. g. in C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^(.*)\r?\n.*", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

or in Python:

```
result = re.sub(r"(?m)^(.*)\r?\n.*", r"\1", subject)
```

Comment: You should also cover the case that there is an odd number of lines.

Comment: Thought so at first, too - but we want to keep the odd lines, don't we? :) By the way, congratulations on being elected moderator - I just noticed the diamond (and I did vote for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, I fully agree with the consensus that this is **not** something regex should be doing.

Here's a Java demo:

```
public class Test {

    public static String voodoo(String lines) {
        return lines.replaceAll("\\G(.*\r?\n).*(?:\r?\n|$)", "$1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("a)\n"+voodoo("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6"));
        System.out.println("b)\n"+voodoo("1\r\n2\n3\r\n4\n5\n6\n7"));
        System.out.println("c)\n"+voodoo("1"));
    }
}
```

output:

```
a)
1
3
5

b)
1
3
5
7

c)
1
```

A short explanation of the regex:

```
\G       # match the end of the previous match
(        # start capture group 1
  .*     #   match any character except line breaks and repeat it zero or more times
  \r?    #   match the character '\r' and match it once or none at all
  \n     #   match the character '\n'
)        # end capture group 1
.*       # match any character except line breaks and repeat it zero or more times
(?:      # start non-capture group 1 
  \r?    #   match the character '\r' and match it once or none at all
  \n     #   match the character '\n'
  |      #   OR
  $      #   match the end of the input
)        # end non-capture group 1
```

`\G` begins at the start of the string. Every pair of lines (where the second line is optional, in case of the last uneven line) gets replaced by the first line in the pair.

But again: using a normal programming language (if one can call `awk` "normal" :)) is the way to go.

**EDIT**

And as Tim suggested, this also works:

```
replaceAll("(?m)^(.*)\r?\n.*", "$1")
```

Comment: Shouldn't `String result = subject.replaceAll("(?m)^(.*)\r?\n.*", "$1");` work just the same? After a match, the regex engine will automatically have arrived at the start of the next odd line.

Comment: Yes, of course it does! As is often the case with me: I try to solve things in a much too difficult way!

Answer (score 2):

I use capture groups (.*) --> $1 in Sublime Text' 'regex-find-replace' mode to
remove the line break in every other line and place a tab character between the values using

```
replace (.*)\n(.*)\n
with $1\t$2\n
```

For this specific question the OP could change this to

```
replace (.*)\n(.*)\n
with $1\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this, will remove EVEN lines from the text file:

```
grep '[13579]$' textfile > textfilewithoddlines
```

And output this:

line1

line3

line5

Comment: Oh yes it is. No matter how large the number, whether it's odd is decided by just the last digit (`$`) which must be one of these 5 digits.

Comment: what i mean by not scalable is that the data may not be a literal "line1", "line2". It may be anything. So grepping for patterns that end with a number is not scalable.

Comment: It is plenty scalable. What ghostdog means is that it's not _general_. Unfortunately the spec (question) doesn't state what kind of generality is required, so we are left to guess.

Comment: @ghostdog74: As OP said he wanted to use regex I assumed he wanted lines ending in odd/even numbers. Otherwise as many says, one wouldn't use regex. `sed -n '2,$n;p' textfile` might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are on the command line. In PowerShell:

```
$x = 0; gc .\foo.txt | ? { $x++;  $x % 2 -eq 0 }
```